# Indy 9 SMTP with attachments 2% failure

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-5

I am using Delphi 5, Indy 9.0.14 SMTP with IdMessSend and the appropriate SSL dlls to send emails with attachments.  98% of recepiants are able to read the attachments, for the others the comments are "this is illegible", "can't open", "unable to view my invoice". and so on.  Identified receiving systems with problems are iPhones, iPad, Blackbury.

Has anybody had this level of failure and if so any idea what caused it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I don't think there's enough information here, and I don't remember any version of Indy with an `IdMessSend` component. Please edit to provide actual information, so we have something to use to try and help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

9.0.14 is old. The last Indy 9 version is 9.0.50.  Indy 9 predates modern mobile devices.  Try upgrading to 9.0.50 and see if it helps any.  If it does not, then try upgrading to Indy 10, which has a more modern email formatting system.  If that still does not work, then you need to provide the actual emails that are failing, and show the actual errors from the email readers, otherwise there is no way to diagnose this problem.